# Is there a way to append only first pages of multiple emails in Outlook?

Tags: vba, printing, outlook

There is way to print only first page of a selected email in outlook. But is there a way to append first pages of multiple emails.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. Body.
2. HTMLBody.
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body. So, **you can use the Word object model do whatever you need with the message body**.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.